# DiagramBuilder: Cannot operate on ports of System plant until it has been registered using AddSystem

Tags: robotics, drake

I have an issue working with `DiagramBuilder` and `ManipulationStation` classes.
It appears to me, that c++ API and the python bindings work differently in my case.
C++ API behaves as expected, while the python bindings result in the runtime error:

`DiagramBuilder: Cannot operate on ports of System plant until it has been registered using AddSystem`

### How I use C++ API

- In one of the `ManipulationStation::Setup...()` methods I inject a block of code, that adds an extra manipuland

```
const std::string sdf_path = FindResourceOrThrow("drake/examples/manipulation_station/models/bolt_n_nut.sdf");
RigidTransform<double> X_WC(RotationMatrix<double>::Identity(), Vector3d(0.0, -0.3, 0.1));
bolt_n_nut_ = internal::AddAndWeldModelFrom(sdf_path, "nut_and_bolt", lant_->world_frame(), "bolt", X_WC, plant_);
```

- I inject another block of code into the method `ManipulationStation::Finalize`:

```
auto zero_torque = builder.template AddSystem<systems::ConstantVectorSource<double>>(Eigen::VectorXd::Zero(plant_->num_velocities(bolt_n_nut_)));
builder.Connect(zero_torque->get_output_port(), plant_->get_actuation_input_port(bolt_n_nut_));
```

With these changes, the simulation runs as expected.

### How I use python bindings

```
plant = station.get_multibody_plant()
manipuland_path = get_manipuland_resource_path()
bolt_with_nut = Parser(plant=plant).AddModelFromFile(manipuland_path)
X_WC = RigidTransform(RotationMatrix.Identity(), [0.0, -0.3, 0.1])
plant.WeldFrames(plant.world_frame(), plant.GetFrameByName('bolt', bolt_with_nut), X_WC)
```

...

```
station.Finalize()
zero_torque = builder.AddSystem(ConstantValueSource(AbstractValue.Make([0.])))
builder.Connect(zero_torque.get_output_port(), plant.get_actuation_input_port(bolt_with_nut_model))
```

This triggers a `RuntimeError` with a message as above; The port, which causes this error is `nut_and_bolt_actuation`.

My vague understanding of the problem is the (in) visibility of `nut_and_bolt` System, due to having two distinct `DiagramBuilder`s in a process: 1) a one is inside `ManipulationStation` 2) another is in the python code, that instantiates this `ManipulationStation` object.

Using `ManipulationStation` via python bindings is a preference for me, because that way I would've avoided depending on a custom build of drake library.

Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your assessment: you have two different `DiagramBuilder` objects here.  This does not have anything to due with C++ or Python; the `ManipulationStation` is itself a `Diagram` (created using its own `DiagramBuilder`), and you have a second `DiagramBuilder` (in either c++ or python) that is connecting the `ManipulationStation` together with other elements. You are trying to connect a system that is in the external diagram to a port that is in the internal diagram, but is not exposed.

The solution would be to have the `ManipulationStation` diagram expose the extra nut and bolt actuation port so that you can connect to it from the second builder.

If you prefer Python, I've switched my course to using a [completely python version of the manipulation station](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/d1c4056e1029fb8fe451828a88cdf5b2868d7bcf/manipulation/scenarios.py#L476). I find this version is much easier to adapt to different student projects.  (To be clear, the setup is in python, but at simulation time all of the elements are c++ and it doesn't call back to python; so the performance is almost identical.)